# Different background or wallpaper per workspace Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with unity 2d. I want to change the wallpaper per workspace, i came across few gconf editor related tutorials but is it possible in any other way? Does unity have it built in or I will have to hack it from these tutorials?

I want it to work on both unity2d and Unity3d.